# Problem solving exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how to get x in this equation:
$$2^x+3^x=7^x$$
I need solution with steps, if possible.

Comment: I doubt this has a sensible closed form solution.  I see $x\approx 0.668849674\cdots$ by numerical methods.

Comment: Its good to say if you are looking for an exact solution, approximate solution or what? Which methods do you know? This helps driving answers you could use.

Comment: I guess he wants to isolate x

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider $f(x)=\left(\dfrac27\right)^x+\left(\dfrac37\right)^x$. Show that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function, and by itv theorem deduce that the equation $f(x)=1$ has a unique solution. Use numerical method to approach the solution.

Comment: I am not sure there is a function in the OP. The OP provided just an equation.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, a closed form solution more than likely does not exits and some numerical method will be required.
Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=7^x-(2^x+3^x)$$ 
DINEDINE showed that there is a unique solution in $(0,1)$.

$f(x)$ varies very fast. So, consider instead
$$g(x)=x\log(7)-\log(2^x+3^x)$$
If you plot it, it looks very much like a straight line and this is very good for Newton method for example.

To have the starting guess, using Taylor at $x=0$ would give
$$g(x)=-\log (2)+x \left(\log(7)-\frac{\log (2)}{2}-\frac{\log (3)}{2}\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, then
$$x_0=\frac{2 \log (2)}{2 \log (7)-\log (2)-\log (3)}$$ Now, Newton iterates would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.660121050806671 \\
 1 & 0.668848170790283 \\
 2 & 0.668849673876579 \\
 3 & 0.668849673876623
\end{array}
\right)$$

Computed for $100$ exact significant figures, inverse symbolic calculators do not identify this number. However, you could be amazed that it is very close ($20$ correct figures) to
$$\frac{127 e^2-441 e-1279}{26 e^2-438 e-1303}$$